# Get header [Authorization] php/apache

Tags: php, apache, centos, authorization

I'm working on a php's function to avoid manual authentication on an intranet application.

I currently use *apache_request_headers()* to get the headers and *$headers['Authorization']* to read the authorization. 
It was fine on my wamp's server (php 5.5.12 & apache 2.4.9) but not on in prod (PHP Version 5.3.3 & Apache 2.2.15 (CentOS)). I'm on internet explorer 8.

So i need your help : What should i check ? How can i get the apache header Authorization with php on Apache 2.2.15 (CentOS) ?

Answer (score 0):

Most client headers are accessible with `$_SERVER['HTTP_xxx']`, for instance, `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']`. This applies to non-standard headers too and should work with all web servers as opposed to being Apache-dependent like your sample code.

However, the `Authorization` header is an exception. PHP decodes that header upon receiving a request and places the username and password respectively in `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your <Directory> or .htaccess:

```
CGIPassAuth On
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#cgipassauth

Comment: This can safely go as a comment